# What subtyping rules does Agda support?

Tags: agda, subtyping

Andrea Vezzosi said Cubical Agda made cubical subtyping coercion-based (`inS` and `outS`) because it's a bad idea to introduce more subtyping relations which complicates the system. Also Agda did not have cumulative universes (it is added now).

So does Agda support any subtyping relations? Without using rewriting and cumulativity options of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The current subtyping rules that Agda uses are for sized types (when `--sized-types` is enabled) and cumulativity (when `--cumulativity` is enabled). Currently neither of these options are allowed under the `--safe` flag, so with `--safe` there is no subtyping in Agda.

There used to be subtyping rules for irrelevant and erased function types as well, but these were removed recently (see [This successful Pull Request which was merged into Master on GitHub](https://github.com/agda/agda/pull/5608)) because they were causing performance problems and anyway only save the user a simple eta-expansion.

Comment: What kind of subtyping does Agda have for sized types? Is it the kind that uses polarity annotations on (co)inductives?